# In MailChimp, how would use a merge tag to check whether someone's using Gmail?

Tags: conditional-statements, mailchimp

Using merge tags in MailChimp, how would I go about detecting whether the recipient is using Gmail, and display a message in the header accordingly?

As an example, here's what I've got in my header now, which fires if a *certain* email address is encountered (as opposed to if gmail.com is seen in the email domain):

```
*|IF:EMAIL=someone@gmail.com|*
Using Gmail? Drag this message to your Primary tab.
 *|END:IF|*
```

Knowing that MailChimp merge tags also supports the following:

```
*|IF:EMAIL != someone@gmail.com|*
You are not someone@gmail.com ...you must be someone else.
 *|END:IF|*
```

Is it possible to show a message in the header only when the recipient is a Gmail user? What operator would I use? Clearly it's not = and it's not !=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailChimp doesn't support partial match functionality in their api.  Your best hope is to process your list as subsets of the master, with domain specific functionality wired into each set.

Comment: Thanks. In MailChimp terms, that means sending a campaign to a "segment" of any given list. In this case, your segment could specify that the email address contains gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

What I've started doing is set up a saved, auto updating segment and then export it, remove everything except email column, and import it (auto updating the list) into an interest group. You can then use the interest group within conditional merge tags (whereas you can't use a segment for that, segments are only for an email send).